# How to precisely position an image on top of a PdfPTable?

Tags: itext

I'm using iText 2.1.6, and I need to precisely position an image over a table, for example:

[image: Precise positioning]

Notice that the image overlays a specific set of rows and columns, and that too some of them partially -- it overlays rows 5 to 13. Of these, it overlays row 5 and row 13 partially, and rows 8-12 completely. Similarly, it overlays columns C and D partially.

In other words, I want to say that the top-left of the image should be in the cell C5, and 4pt below and 6pt to the right of the top-left of C5.

How do I do this? I thought I'll add the text to the table, add the table to the Document, and then query the table to get the absolute positions of the rows and columns, and then add the image to the Document at that position, perhaps in direct content mode.

But the table may split across pages, because it may have hundreds of rows. In that case, I need to add the image to the right page, and at the right position.

Is there a recommended way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: This is really easy to achieve with a table or a cell event. Unfortunately, you're using an unsupported version of iText. Please upgrade!

Comment: Thanks, again. I will take a look at those. I have already initiated the process of upgrading, but it will take time. In the meantime, I have to work with the version I have. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written some sample code that uses a table event. In the [`AddOverlappingImage`](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/AddOverlappingImage) class, we create a table and declare a table event. This table event looks like this:

```
public class ImageContent implements PdfPTableEvent {
    protected Image content;
    public ImageContent(Image content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
    public void tableLayout(PdfPTable table, float[][] widths,
            float[] heights, int headerRows, int rowStart,
            PdfContentByte[] canvases) {
        try {
            PdfContentByte canvas = canvases[PdfPTable.TEXTCANVAS];
            float x = widths[3][1] + 10;
            float y = heights[3] - 10 - content.getScaledHeight();
            content.setAbsolutePosition(x, y);
            canvas.addImage(content);
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            throw new ExceptionConverter(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I pass an `Image` to the event class and in the `tableLayout()` method, I add the image to the 4th row and the 2nd column (the index starts counting at 0).

I hard-coded the cell position. Obviously, you should use some parameters, for instance a `List` of images and coordinates.